# finding string in beutifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

i'm searching for the text `City` immediately prior to the tag I want: the city and state string. Here is the html:

```
<b>City:</b>
  <a href="/city/New-York-New-York.html">New York, NY</a>
```

here is the code:

```
zipCode = str(11021)
url = "http://www.city-data.com/zips/" + zipCode + ".html"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
main_body = soup.findAll(text="City:")
print main_body
```

All I get, however, are empty brackets. How do I search for the `City:` text and then get the string for the next tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next_elements` from the text node until you find an `<a>` tag and extract its text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'html')

for t in soup.find_all(text="City:"):
    print(t)
    for e in t.next_elements:
        if e.name == 'a':
            print(e.string)
            break
```

Run it like (asumming `htmlfile` has the test data of the question):

```
python3 script.py htmlfile
```

That yields:

```
City:
New York, NY
```

Comment: @JonClements: Yes. I didn't realise of that option. Much easier and clearer.

Comment: @JonClements do I have to use sys.argv...etc?  I tried just using the 'for t...' loop and got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

answers from @Birei and @JohnClements got me most of the way there, but here is code that works for me:

```
zipCode = str("07928")
url = "http://www.city-data.com/zips/" + zipCode + ".html"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
if soup.findAll(text="City:") ==[]:
    cityNeeded = soup.findAll(text="Cities:")
    for t in cityNeeded:
        print t.find_next('a').string
else:
    cityNeeded = soup.findAll(text="City:")
    for t in cityNeeded:
        print t.find_next('a').string
```